# Maven central repo does not reflect latest 1.3.0 artifact, any other repos I can pull from?

Tags: java, maven, scribe

I'm working with a basic Java app on Heroku utilizing scribe for OAuth access to the Meetup API. I'm pulling the dependency via maven and it appears that the artifact served up by the central repo is missing some of the latest APIs despite carrying the 1.3.0 version.

Explore the artifact found here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scribe/scribe/1.3.0 and you'll find org.scribe.builder.api.MeetupApi as well as several others missing.

Any other repos out there I can use to get at the latest version rather than supplying the artifact myself? Since the devs are subscribed, maybe a chance of getting central updated? I'll likely be using this app for a walk-through lab, so being able to pull the dependency rather than provide it would be a real time saver.

Thanks for your time!

SOLVED: I was actually seeking out features of 1.3.1, which is not yet released. See my answer below for how I made an in-project repo to house my own build of 1.3.1 until release.

Comment: Hey sorry I'll upload the jar to the github downloads page

Comment: Actually `1.3.0` is already there: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/downloads

Comment: Thanks for stopping in. A version 1.3.0 is there, but the code's not up to date. There are still several APIs missing when compared to the master branch on github. The download artifact on github is the same...it shows version 1.3.0, but the code within does not align with master.

Comment: `1.3.0` is the latest stable release (check the tag with the same name). Master is what will become `1.3.1`, yet unreleased.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's what I was missing then. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out an alternative way to accomplish this using an in-project repository which allowed me to avoid using a system scope on a dependency. I added a lib directory to my project:

```
lib/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.1
```

I then cloned the latest scribe project code and did a mvn install, then copied the jar and pom files from my local .m2 repo into the new directory within my project. I then included the new localalized repo in my pom like so:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

We have faced a similar kind of problem. The best thing to do in such cases might be create own repository , May be [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) will help you to quickly get started on creating a repository with custom library versions.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered using Archiva for this. I guess I was hoping I could talk a dev into updating their downloads on the project since the code is integrated into master.